# ssh from MAC osx 10.8.5 connection refused

Tags: macos, ssh

What could be the problem here with my MAC osx 10.8.5 and SSH?
I can ping the remote machine from my Mac OSX 10.8.5.
I can ssh to the remote machine from another Linux machine.
But, I cannot ssh to the remote machine from my MAC whether using IP address or the long name.
I was able to do this before, now it no longer works. I don't know how this happened.
I installed NoMachine on my MAC, but i'm not sure if this caused it.

```
$ ssh -vvv 73.x.x.x_some_ipaddress
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 73.x.x.x port 22.
debug1: connect to address 73.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 73.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: i upvoted your question user2880690.  Keep it real.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** a machine received your request and sent something back saying "Nothing is listening here" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment

"Connection refused" is different than "Connection timeout". It means that your machine sent a syn (or synchronize) packet to initiate a connection and that it received a tcp rst (or reset) packet in response. This can happen if the remote machine received your request to initiate a connection but no process is listening on that port. From your question it sounds like you have tested that not to be the case. The next most obvious thing that would generate a rst packet in response to an outgoing ssh request is a firewall. Are all the machines on the same local network? Is there a firewall or AWS security group or anything else in between the server and the client that may be filtering requests.

Just so you know, a firewall can be configured to drop packets instead of respond to them. That would result in your ssh client taking several-many seconds to time out.

Your question was voted down because it has little to do with programming and more to do with networking and system administration. It would have been nice for the person who did that to explain why they voted it down. In the future, you may want to consider posting questions like this to one of the other stack exchange websites like ServerFault. You can access a list of these sites here: https://stackexchange.com/sites